# Where could I find a reliable source that states all the existing radioactive decays?

Tags: nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, radioactivity, data

According to searches on many sources on the web and books, I could merge informations to deduce that the *general* possible radioactive decay modes are the following:

- $\alpha$ (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_decay )
- $\beta$ (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay)
- electronic capture (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture)
- proton emission (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_emission )
- neutron emission (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_emission)
- heavy ion decay (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_decay )
- spontaneous fission (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_fission)
- intern conversion : (proof that this is a type of radioctivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_conversion)
- isomeric transition: (proof that this is a type of radioactivity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer#Decay_processes)

Now, I am not able to find a *single* document (reliable if possible) that states all the *general* existing radioactive decay mode?

Does it exist? Which one?
If not, why?

Comment: You should state how you define “radioactive”.

Comment: In my opinion it is a vague and confusing term that encompasses a variety of completely unrelated fundamental interactions.

Comment: @G. Smith : I'm not the one who defines the terms radioactive and radioactivity. Scientific community does define it. We could consider wikipedia definition : "Radioactive decay is the process by which an *unstable* atomic nucleus loses energy by radiation".

Comment: How about ENSDF? https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/

Comment: When you say "mode" are you limiting it to each general process, or are you looking for every specific nuclide which decays and every type of decay the nuclide can undergo? In other words, a small list or a HUGE list?

Comment: @anna v : thank you. I have fixed the word.

Comment: @Bill N : I keep to "general" process. So a small list.

Comment: You should add that info to your question. Otherwise, more people are likely to misinterpret your question.

Comment: thank you, I have added it

Answer (score 2):

The standard source for decays is the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File site(s), which serves the nuclear physics community. I happen to mostly use the site hosted at [Brookhaven](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/EnsdfDispatcherServlet#) but there are mirrors around the world if you access time is a bit long. The site is where data on nuclear structure is gathered and provided to the world.

You can search on nucleide (mass) to see all the ways known to get to a given isotope (and all the gamma levels), or the fancier 'By Decay' search engine, which I will let you play with.

Comment: thank you, but I search for *general* modes of radioactivity in a single document, not the decays of each nucleus.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian - well, go look at the ‘By Decay’ tab and you will see all known decay paths, and can get a list of nuclei exhibiting that channel.

Comment: ah yes. Thank you